# Can no longer import xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost

I have installed Anaconda 3 and lots of packages, including `xgboost` few months ago and it worked well. But now `xgboost` stopped working: import fails with

> OSError:
>   /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/../../../../libstdc++.so.6:
>   version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by
>   /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so)

I do see `libstdc++.so.6` in my `lib` dir. What might have gone wrong?

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything?

Comment: This is an option, but may be there's an easier way?

Comment: that's probably the easiest way. you could try reinstalling `libstdc++` like `apt-get install libstdc++`, but I don't guarantee that will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it. Here's what I did

```
conda install libgcc
```

From [this issue](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1043).